# OpenModelica IBPSA example error spatialDistribution

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm quite new to Modelica and I'm trying to understand some basic examples. I'm looking at the example IBPSA.Fluid.FixedResistances.Examples.PlugFlowPipe and checking this model gives me the following error

```
Number of classes to check: 2 
Checking: model IBPSA.Fluid.FixedResistances.Examples.PlugFlowPipe... 0.2350000000001273 seconds -> FAILED! 

Error String: 

Error Buffer: 
Warning: Requested package Modelica of version 3.2.2, but this package was already loaded with version 3.2.3. You might experience problems if these versions are incompatible. 
[C:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.0-64bit/lib/omlibrary/IBPSA 3.0.0/Fluid/FixedResistances/BaseClasses/PlugFlowTransportDelay.mo:49:3-55:44:writable] Error: Function argument initialValues={time + pip.cor.timDel.t_in_start, time + pip.cor.timDel.t_out_start} in call to spatialDistribution has variability continuous which is not a parameter expression. 

#[-], 0.2350000000001273, IBPSA.Fluid.FixedResistances.Examples.PlugFlowPipe 
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Checking skipped: package IBPSA.Fluid.FixedResistances.Examples.PlugFlowPipe.Medium...  


[2] 11:48:12 Scripting Notification
Number of classes checked / failed: 2/1
```

It seems that the module `pip.cor.timDel` uses the function `spatialDistributuon`. My guess is that there is something wrong with `pip.cor.timDel.t_in_start` or `pip.cor.timDel.t_out_start`? It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this.

P.S. I'm using OMEdit v1.14.0 on windows 10 with Modelica library v3.2.3

Comment: same question asked here: https://github.com/ibpsa/modelica-ibpsa/issues/1272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenModelica does not support the function `spatialDistribution` yet, i opened a ticket on [Trac](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5765#) where you can follow for the current development status.